# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'singleton') - Adonisjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, adonis.js

An error occurs when tender registers a singleton-type Service.

I'm using IocContract

AppProvider

```
export default class AppProvider {
  constructor(
    protected app: ApplicationContract,
    protected $container: IocContract
  ) {}

  public register() {
    // Register your own bindings
    this.$container.singleton(
      'Front/RegraService',
      () => new RegraService()
    )
  }
```

Error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'singleton')

Comment: sending "$container" don't make it available in "this"

Comment: import { IocContract } from '@adonisjs/fold'

Comment: export default class AppProvider {
$container = null;
  constructor(
    protected app: ApplicationContract,
    protected $container: IocContract
  ) {
$container = container;
}

  public register() {
    // Register your own bindings
    this.$container.singleton(
      'Front/RegraService',
      () => new RegraService()
    )
  }

Comment: This is a construct  - protected $container: IocContract

Comment: thinking that "$container" need to be a property in the class and to be updated through the constructor.

Comment: with $container = null - Does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export default class AppProvider {
  constructor(protected app: ApplicationContract) {}

  public register() {
    this.app.container.singleton('Front/RegraService', () => new RegraService())
  }
}
```

Comment: @ref https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/auth/custom-user-provider#registering-the-user-provider :))